# Are there tutorials for Elastic Beanstalk that include use of JPA or Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It is easy to create a simple web app that runs in Elastic Beanstalk.

It seems like apps that are designed to run on a local instance of Tomcat and access a database using JPA and/or Hibernate add a level of complexity that is not covered though.

I sure hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The travel log sample (http://aws.amazon.com/code/1264287584622066) uses SimpleJPA to store data in SimpleDB.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is an article that goes 'step by step' from the single jsp EB project to travel log?

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience using maven to do webapps, see the docs for my maven plugin, beanstalker, which contains how to deploy it.

http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/